# Python for .NET subscribes to C# event but throws ConversionException

Tags: c#, python, .net, events

I have a DLL that exposes this C# event:

```
[Serializable]
public delegate object[] MyEventHandler(object[] data);

event MyEventHandler MyEvent;
```

and python code which subscribes to it:

```
...
def MyPythonEventHandler(source, args):
    print 'Inside Event Handler'
...
ref.MyEvent += MyPythonEventHandler
...
```

When the DLL fires the event, the print statement in MyPythonEventHandler is not reached; instead Python throws a ConversionException. Because the exception isn't serializable, the DLL actually receives this exception:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type 'Python.Runtime.
ConversionException' in Assembly 'Python.Runtime, Version=2.0.0.2, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.
```

So I can't actually tell what conversion is being attempted and is failing.

I successfully handle other event callbacks from this DLL, so I'm guessing this failure has to do with this particular event's delegate signature. Is my python handler's signature wrong?

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a bare bones DLL with one class containing the delegate, event and a Run method that fires the event. Stripped down my python to create the object, subscribe and run. Immediately got an error indicating I hadn't declared a function named MyPythonEventHandler. Found a typo in the name.

Don't get why Python didn't reort this error in the original script, but it works now that I've fixed the name.